# Find the number of series with a certain condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Q: Calculate the number of series: $a_1a_2a_3 \dots a_n$ of length $n$ that for all $a_i \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and there is no occurrence of $3$ right of $0$.
Meaning: no $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$ exist so that $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ and $a_j = 3 , a_i = 0$

I tried to approach this in a combinatoric way, by drawing:

$ \_ ,\_, \dots\_ $ and filling what I know. Starting for the first _ with a 3, so we cannot use $0$ anywhere else and so the number of options is $3^{n-1}$
And we do it for each $\_$ (meaning we move one forward and do the whole thing again) and what I get is: $\sum_1^n 3^{n-1} = 3^{n-1} \cdot n$

However I am not sure at all if this is the solution, I can't seem to understand what is the trick here... thank you!

Comment: No $3$ *anywhere* to the left of a zero? or no $3$ *immediately* to the left of a zero?

Comment: @GerryMyerson by the rule of i and j i understand that no 3 left to 0 not only consecutive

Comment: For $n=2$ your formula gives $6$ but it's easy to write down a lot more than that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I counted 15 for n=2 oops

Comment: The only forbidden sequence is $30$, so you should get $15$ (which agrees with the answer you have accepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that altogether we have $j\leq n$ $0$'s and $3$'s.  There are $\binom nj$ places we can choose to place them in the sequence, and only one order they can go in: first all the $0$'s, then all the $3$'s.  There can be from $0$ to $j$ $0$'s, so $j+1$ possibilities.  Now each of the remaining $n-j$ places can be occupied by a $1$ or a $2$, so we have $2^{n-j}$ ways to complete the sequence.  Altogether the number of admissible sequences is 
$$\begin{align}
S:&=\sum_{j=0}^n (j+1)2^{n-j}\binom nj\\
&=2^n\sum_{j=0}^n j2^{-j}\binom nj+2^n\sum_{j=0}^n 2^{-j}\binom nj\tag1
\end{align}$$ 
Recall the binomial theorem.$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj x^j\tag2$$
Differentiating both sides of $(2)$, we have $$
n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{j=0}^n j\binom nj x^{j-1}\tag3$$

Now if we set $x=\frac12$, $(2)$ shows that the second term of $(1)$ is $$2^n\left(1+\frac12\right)^n=3^n,$$ and $(3)$ shows that the first term of $(1)$ is $$2^{n-1}\left(1+\frac12\right)^{n-1}=n\cdot3^{n-1}$$ so the final answer is $$\boxed{(n+3)3^{n-1}}$$

I must say I couldn't follow your calculation, but it seems like you may just have missed the sequences with no $3$'s at all.

**EDIT**

Now that I know the answer, I see a better way of doing it.  There are $n$ places the last $0$ in the sequence can be.  Any number before it can be $0,1,\text{ or }2$, and any number after it can be $1,2,\text{ or }3$, which gives $n\cdot3^{n-1}$ sequences containing a $0$, and of course there are $3^n$ admissible sequences with no $0$.

Your argument must be similar, except that you are considering the first $3$ instead of the last $0$.

Comment: Wait now I see something odd in my question, I said no 3 to the left of a 0, but i said:   no $i,j∈N$ exist so that $1≤i<j≤n$ and $aj=3,ai=0$ which is actually 3 to the right of 0 and that is what the question is about, no 3 to the right of 0 . does this solution hold? I am so sorry...

Comment: @StackOMeow It's just a typo.  It doesn't really matter; the problem is symmetric in left and right.   Actually your solution is very good.  I missed where you said you were talking about the *first 3*.   You should, in my opinion, have been been more explicit about your calculations, but the only real error you made was overlooking the sequences with no $3$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!